# Unable to Sign-in in Bot Framework for Microsoft Teams channel

Tags: authentication, botframework, microsoft-teams

When trying to click on Sign In , nothing happens in Microsoft Teams. It does not open the iframe/browswer to sign in. I am calling OAuthPrompt like below.  this works fine in Webchat .

```
return await stepcontext.BeginDialogAsync(oatuhloginpromptname, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);


  private OAuthPrompt Prompt(string connectionName)
    {
        return new OAuthPrompt(
            oatuhloginpromptname,
            new OAuthPromptSettings
            {
                ConnectionName = connectionName,
                Text = "Please Sign In ",
                Title = "Sign In",
                Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a manifest and include token.botframework.com in the `validDomains` section, because otherwise the Sign in button will not open the authentication window. Use the [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio) to generate your manifest for example.

Read more: [using Azure Bot Service for Authentication in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

**Update**:
The [v4.3 update](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/releases/tag/4.3) changed the OAuthCard for Teams, so that it will also work without creating the manifest.